# What files from the debug folder needed for deployment?

Tags: c#, deployment, console-application

From the bin > Debug folder it's clear I will need to copy the executable and the main config file to whatever machine I need to run this basic console application on. What other files are needed (what is the manifest file's purpose for example)?

Thanks.

Comment: none, deploy from the Release folder instead

Comment: compile in release mode... those little drop down list in the middle of the toolbar. You should always do this!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll remember to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy

- Executable
- Related assemblies
- Configuration File

This is the basic stuff. There might be more, but that depends on your specific case.

For debugging purposes you might consider moving .pdb files.

As other people already said, for production purposes you're supposed to deploy the release build and not the debug one.

Comment: Why do we see .pdb files in Release folder? I thought it is supposed to be in Debug folder only?

Comment: @MerinNakarmi: because your release build is set to generate them. It's not true that a release build can't be debugged :)

Comment: Could you please guide me where I can disable getting debug related files in the Release folder?

Comment: @MerinNakarmi: what visual studio version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 3):

In general, you'll only need the application, the config file, and any dependencies (other assemblies you reference).

That being said, for deployment, you'll typically want to deploy the release build, not the debug build.  Also, if deploying to other systems, you may want to consider making a setup project, which will handle dependencies, including the .NET framework itself.